# Does anybody have a zenburn colour theme for VS2010 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, color-scheme

I can't get the VS 2008 settings with the Zenburn colours to import into VS 2010 RC, and wondered if anybody had the theme working and could make the settings available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [studiostyles](http://studiostyl.es/) there is [style](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/zenburn-2010) based on Zenburn.

In download page you can choose your version of Visual Studio (2005, 2008 or 2010).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 2010, but this might work for you.  A co-worker was able to import a copy of my 2008 settings into 2005 by changing the version number (9 to 8) in the settings file.

Comment: Changing the version number to 10 did work. Silly me for not trying that before. Have 100 points.